# Maven command `mvn -v` waits forever

Tags: maven

When executing `mvn -v` command on Windows PC, it waits forever without giving a result. When the wifi is turned off and executes the same command, it gives the expected result. But when I connect to the internet back, it hangs again.

mvn version - 3.8.7
java version - Oracle 17.0.6

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: What is the result of `mvn -v`

Comment: This sounds like a network issue if the JVM tries to do a host name lookup.  Is this also the case right after a reboot? When using cabled network?

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski - It doesn't give any results. Just keeps hanging.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Yes I used a cabled network and even after rebooting it's the same. When I tried with a mobile hotspot, it gave the expected result. But later on, that also didn't work. It seems like an intermittent issue.

Comment: Try `jps` - to find java process pid and next `jstack`, please provide output of  `jstack` for handling process

Comment: I still suspect your network configuration. A thread dump may confirm this.